# Office 365 Exchange Rules - Delete on Arrive

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

I have a sales shared mailbox on Office 365 Exchange Online and I have rules to forward messages to employees. I was wondering if there is a way using rules or another alternative to delete the emails in this mailbox when they arrive because I don't want to fill this mailbox up due to best practices in mind.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Define `fill up`. What best practice are you referring to specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We setup the policy that removes items from the recycle bin after X days.  People can then setup a rule to move mail (happens without the client having to be running) to the bin and they will simply cycle themselves out.

Comment: Ill investigate this method, seems pretty solid. Thanks for your input.

Comment: yeah, this way also has the benefit of having items in the bin for when that manager or clueless tech has an important email sent to that account for "reasons"...